# Are double splats treated differently in methods?

Tags: crystal-lang

When I used a double splat for a method, I'm not allowed to define a variable with a type within the method:

```
def show(**attrs)
  place : String = "w"
  puts place
end

show(name: "Bobby")  # This works.

show(name: "Bobby", place: "World") # This fails:
#
#in tmp.cr:2: variable 'place' already declared
#
#  place : String = "w"
#  ^~~~~
```

Is this the expected behaviour when using double splats? I couldn't find anything in the Crystal Book about this: https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/splats_and_tuples.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug, please report it as such.

Note that declaring local variables with a type is not a recommended practice. Because it was a recent addition, it is not well tested and apparently prone to bugs.

You can see that this works, anyway:

```
def show(**attrs)
  place = "w"
  puts place
  puts attrs[:place]
end

show(name: "Bobby", place: "World")
```

```
w
World
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. So my misuse exposed a bug in the compiler. Nice.

Comment: Posted and labeled as a `bug, compiler`: https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/5693